# How to fing Servers and services in windows machine which is monitored by SCOM?

Tags: c#, sdk, scom

I am Using SCOM tool to Monitor windows system.Using C# code and SDK i should get details of Platform and server and services it is using.I am able to get Platfroms .Can any one help to get server from platform.

Here is my code.

```
        ManagementGroup mgGroup = new ManagementGroup(mgGroupConnection);
        if (!mgGroup.IsConnected)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Not connected to an SDK Service.");
        }



        MonitoringClassCriteria classCriteria = new MonitoringClassCriteria("Name = 'Microsoft.Windows.Computer'OR Name='Microsoft.Linux.Computer'");
        Console.WriteLine("Querying for data...");
        ReadOnlyCollection<MonitoringClass> monitoringClasses = mgGroup.GetMonitoringClasses(classCriteria);
        ReadOnlyCollection<MonitoringObject> monitoringObjects = mgGroup.GetMonitoringObjects(monitoringClasses[0]);

        if (monitoringObjects.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (MonitoringObject objects in monitoringObjects)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Monitoring Object name: " + objects.DisplayName + Environment.NewLine);
                DisplayPropertyValues(objects);
                Console.WriteLine(objects.HealthState.ToString());
}
}
    public static void DisplayPropertyValues(MonitoringObject mObject)
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Property value information: ");
        foreach (MonitoringClassProperty property in mObject.GetMonitoringProperties())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("    " + property.Name + " = " + ((mObject.GetMonitoringPropertyValue(property) != null) ? mObject.GetMonitoringPropertyValue(property).ToString() : "NULL"));
        }

    }`
```

Output:

```
 Querying for data...
Monitoring Object name: SCOM1.IMTS.TEST


Property value information:
    IsVirtualNode = NULL
    PrincipalName = SCOM1.IMTS.TEST
    DNSName = SCOM1.IMTS.TEST
    NetbiosComputerName = SCOM1
    NetbiosDomainName = IMTS
    IPAddress = 192.168.147.7, fe80::619d:83dd:1edc:cf32
    NetworkName = SCOM1.IMTS.TEST
    ActiveDirectoryObjectSid = NULL
    IsVirtualMachine = True
    DomainDnsName = IMTS.TEST
    OrganizationalUnit = CN=Computers,DC=IMTS,DC=TEST
    ForestDnsName = IMTS.TEST
    ActiveDirectorySite = Default-First-Site-Name
    LogicalProcessors = 2
    PhysicalProcessors = 1
    HostServerName = RD24BE05B7D840
    VirtualMachineName = 668ff774-591e-4e2b-990a-7ea00147846c
    OffsetInMinuteFromGreenwichTime = NULL
    LastInventoryDate = NULL
    DisplayName = SCOM1.IMTS.TEST
    InstallDirectory = C:\Program Files\Microsoft System Center 2012 R2\Operations
Manager\Server\
Success
criteria Name LIKE '%Memory%'
Monitoring Object name: activedirectory.imts.test


Property value information:
    IsVirtualNode = NULL
    PrincipalName = ActiveDirectory.IMTS.TEST
    DNSName = ActiveDirectory.IMTS.TEST
    NetbiosComputerName = ActiveDirectory
    NetbiosDomainName = IMTS
    IPAddress = 192.168.147.6
    NetworkName = ActiveDirectory.IMTS.TEST
    ActiveDirectoryObjectSid = S-1-5-21-1598398879-2601050756-607317532-1001
    IsVirtualMachine = True
    DomainDnsName = IMTS.TEST
    OrganizationalUnit = OU=Domain Controllers,DC=IMTS,DC=TEST
    ForestDnsName = IMTS.TEST
    ActiveDirectorySite = Default-First-Site-Name
    LogicalProcessors = 2
    PhysicalProcessors = 1
    HostServerName = RD008CFA118C0A
    VirtualMachineName = 9c55d1d2-0fe6-4942-bc49-78d914464b9f
    OffsetInMinuteFromGreenwichTime = NULL
    LastInventoryDate = NULL
    DisplayName = activedirectory.imts.test
    InstallDirectory = C:\Program Files\Microsoft Monitoring Agent\Agent\
Success
```